# Control That Can OverLeap WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, wpf

as i know other control like button , Image and ... can not be overleap on webbrowser control and it is on top as we set zindex property !
on of control that overleap web browser control is popup , is there any other way or control to overleap ?!

Comment: This might not work because the WebBrowser control is internally using the IE ActiveX object, which means that its real estate is controlled by native code, so sharing the same real estate with WPF that internally use DirectX won't work.

Comment: Airspace issue, I ran into it when plotting charts for my WPF application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: WebBrowser uses a window, the browser renders the page into that window.  Overlapping it requires another window, not a UIElement.  ChildWindow is the base class in WPF.

Comment: You could try switching to [this WPF control](http://wpfchromium4.codeplex.com/) which provides a wrapper for the same browser engine as Google Chrome, and doesn't have the same airspace issues.

Comment: 3d party has some problem like not supporting jquery or unicode  or font-face or bad parsing! problem solved with hosting winform control that want to overleap on webbrowser in wpf application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved problem with hosting controls that want to overleap on webbrowser with `Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF` More Info [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx)